# how to pick an object from json string based on a condition in react native

Tags: json, reactjs, native

I have a big list of client data in json format and need to display client details based on conditions, e.g. `status='active'`, `id=1003` etc. 
how can this be done in react native

example client list

```js
"data": {
  "items": [{
      "id": 1001,
      "name": "CName1",
      "address": "New Street 1",
      "phone": null,
      "status": "active"
    },
    {
      "id": 1002,
      "name": "CName2",
      "address": "New Street 2",
      "phone": null,
      "status": "deleted"
    },
    {
      "id": 1003,
      "name": "CName3",
      "address": "New Street 3",
      "phone": null,
      "status": "active"
    },
    {
      "id": 1004,
      "name": "CName4",
      "address": "New Street 4",
      "phone": null,
      "status": "suspended"
    }
  ]
}
```

How can I list all 'active' clients from this list Or list details of client id 1003 in react native

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use filter method here.

```
const statusActiveArr = data.items.filter(item => item.status === 'active');

const specificIdClient = data.items.filter(item => item.id === 1003)[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing with react native. If you want to filter items from array, you can use [`.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter).

For example, to filter based on `status` you can do:

```
data.items.filter(item => item.status === 'active')
```

If you want to find specific item (e.g. based on `id` so only one result will filtered) you can use [`.find()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find)

```
data.items.find(item => item.id === 1001)
```

Live example:

```js
const data = {
  "items": [{
      "id": 1001,
      "name": "CName1",
      "address": "New Street 1",
      "phone": null,
      "status": "active"
    },
    {
      "id": 1002,
      "name": "CName2",
      "address": "New Street 2",
      "phone": null,
      "status": "deleted"
    },
    {
      "id": 1003,
      "name": "CName3",
      "address": "New Street 3",
      "phone": null,
      "status": "active"
    },
    {
      "id": 1004,
      "name": "CName4",
      "address": "New Street 4",
      "phone": null,
      "status": "suspended"
    }
  ]
}

const filtered = data.items.filter(item => item.status === 'active')
console.log(filtered);
```

Comment: Thank you... Im new to this, it really helped